# Inserting the Records into 2 different Databases(both SQL server) at same time

Tags: java, sql-server, database, architecture

I am in situation that i need to insert the Record from stand alone Java code (JMSListner) to 2 different databases.Both DB is MS SQL servers and having same table and schema. At the same time I have to make sure that both database is exactly replica of each other; that means the if to first DB insertions success and to another one it fails then I have to rollback transaction from first DB also.

Now from the Solution prospective, i found that we can use XA transaction to achieve this , but the problem there is no open source DB pool available that support XA transaction. I am using already CP30 db pool. Then I started to writing the as usual insertion code where I created 2 connection for 2 databases then  set autoCommitt as false, then do the commit for both DB at last. but the Problem here is after successful commit of One db if second commit fails , then I need to rollback from the first DB. so I did connection.rollback, but that's does not work once success commit happens and MS doc also tells the same.

Now I am in fix that how I can achieve this scenario. please guide us.

Comment: how about you set up a replication between the two databases? then you would only have to insert into 1 and only successfully committed data will be replicated to the 2nd database. a guide i used to set a [replication](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-master-slave-replication-in-mysql)

Comment: That would be the best approach, but client is not ready to do that.so I don't have that option

Comment: what do you mean with `client is not ready to do that`? another approach would be to save the data you recently inserted until both transactions were successfully committed and if one fails, you know which data you have to delete or try the insert again

Comment: @XtremeBaumer, DB lies to client end environment, and we don't have any access to that.  we don't have any ask to get that as well.

Comment: maybe you can do it directly [within the server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb986830.aspx) to which you should have access anyways. if you don't have access, how do you want to connect to the database?

Comment: one port is opened to connect the connection string. I understand your point but at the end its client, they gave multiple reason not setup the replica since they have the Reporting ODS on that other constraint is also involve here...

Comment: well okay, then you should totally "remember" which data you want to insert until both transactions are committed. if one fails, either try again or delete the data from the database with the successful transaction. (i would suggest to try it again)

Comment: we remember the each data until commit, because we are streaming from AMQ. so you are suggesting to if unsuccessful, the via delete script deletes it from success one.....Any other solution?

Comment: try reinserting on the failed server. nothing else i can think of for now

Comment: If the client does not want to do it the proper way then you will be left with a less than ideal solution. There is no magic answer here. You can't commit the transaction across multiple databases at the same time so you are left to design logic to either a) rollback or b) retry.

Comment: @Jacob, Can't do Rollback also, because as I mentioned earlier, Once successful Commit occurs, the connection.rollback had no effect. Okie, How about XA transactions? any experience ? with XA , I have to skip connectionPool.